# Каскадное удаление без включенного каскадного удаления

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли явно как-нибудь вызвать каскадное удаление в момент выполнения инструкции Delete, когда оно отключено?

Comment: [Ответ на английском SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116968/in-sql-server-2005-can-i-do-a-cascade-delete-without-setting-the-property-on-my) подходит?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, если прокоментируете, что происходит с крипте и что означает каждая связь.

Comment: Могу рассказать основные мысли:
1. взаимосвязи таблиц через Foreign keys можно извлечь через системное представление (system view) sys.foreign_keys.
2. затем итерируюсь по этим метаданным заполняется таблица данных для удаления.
3. Затем динамически генерируются скрипты для удаления.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/116968/5727271 вот хороший вопрос с ответами на английском, про каскадное удаление вообще.